# Translate name of Windows Feature from Powershell to DISM

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2016, dism

I have a list of Windows Feature I want to install with DISM but I only know what their names are when using PowerShell.

Is there a way to quickly "translate" these names? It's more than a handful:

1. NET-Framework-45-Features
2. RPC-over-HTTP-proxy
3. RSAT-Clustering
4. RSAT-Clustering-CmdInterface
5. RSAT-Clustering-Mgmt
6. RSAT-Clustering-PowerShell
7. Web-Mgmt-Console
8. WAS-Process-Model
9. Web-Asp-Net45
10. Web-Basic-Auth
11. Web-Client-Auth
12. Web-Digest-Auth
13. Web-Dir-Browsing
14. Web-Dyn-Compression
15. Web-Http-Errors
16. Web-Http-Logging
17. Web-Http-Redirect
18. Web-Http-Tracing
19. Web-ISAPI-Ext
20. Web-ISAPI-Filter
21. Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console
22. Web-Metabase
23. Web-Mgmt-Console
24. Web-Mgmt-Service
25. Web-Net-Ext45
26. Web-Request-Monitor
27. Web-Server
28. Web-Stat-Compression
29. Web-Static-Content
30. Web-Windows-Auth
31. Web-WMI
32. Windows-Identity-Foundation
33. RSAT-ADDS

So I would like something other than toggling the feature with PowerShell and check for changes in the dism command's output. Hopefully there's a better way... :)

Answer (score 2):

It's usually a bad idea to install Server Features with DISM. *Install-WindowsFeature* can target offline images if that's what you're trying.  Online, *Install-WindowsFeature* integrates with plug-ins from the various role and feature teams that may do additional configuration or checks to ensure your server stays healthy.

That said, to answer your specific question and keeping in mind the "buyer beware" comments above...

```
Get-WindowsFeature <featurename> |% { $_.AdditionalInfo.InstallName }
```

I was the dev manager for this feature area, so please trust me when I there are very few reasons to go the DISM route - but let's discuss in comments if you're in that category.  I do also have a code snippet someplace that will capture before and after doing an install, and can create the equivalent DISM command line.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to map them by toggling them in PowerShell and then checking

```
Dism /online /Get-Features
```

Not sure if there is an automatic mapping though. Sorry, that doesn't cover the 'quickly'.